# Server-sided redirection with Google Optimize A/B testing

Tags: php, optimization, analytics, measurement-protocol

We have a page with multiple layouts. The difference between these layouts, and the way they're generated, is significant enough that they need to be done server-side, in PHP.

To A/B test these layouts, we created a page redirect experiment via Google Optimize, which would add a custom variable in the URL `https://website.test/page?layout_id=123`. This worked fine, but the problem with this is the delay between the page load and when the DOM is ready, forcing the client to see the original layout before they're redirected.

We then decided to move the redirect to the server-side script in PHP.

One way is using https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol/ (which is based on Google's Measurement Protocol) and according to https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments#implement-experiment, we need to decide on our own which variant to serve, however, it still requires a `clientId` or `userId` to identify the client and this is only delivered via a cookie called `_ga`, after the first load.

The problem with this approach is that users visiting the page for the first time cannot be identified, and therefore it messes the results.

What is the best approach for such a situation, where the server needs to know in advance what layout to deliver?

Comment: can you refresh the page if `_ga` cookie not found? so at second time it will show you the cookie.

Comment: @jagad89 That would result in the same behavior as having Google Optimize do the refresh. The only other alternative is leaving the A/B test up to the server, so even if there's no client ID, we will decide a variant and show that layout, save the decision in session, and whenever the `_ga` cookie is found, we'll notify Google Analytics. But isn't there a better way? What do large companies do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this question is still relevant but we implemented our own mechanics (a simple A/B testing engine in PHP) which determines what page/code to show. The Optimize is only used to setup the variants and track the results.

Here is a document from google that explains it:
https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments

Comment: This is an alternative version that doesn't take full advantage of Google Analytics / Optimize identifying and tracking individual users (because you have to decide the variant and cannot tell which users should see which variants on repeated visits), but it works.

Comment: Very true, but like you found out, it's still a better user experience than having to double refresh or change the content after the page is loaded. I am afraid any 'out of the box' JavaScript solution would have this issue, that's why I prefer the server side solution.